# union and select based on conditions

Tags: sql, hana

I have two tables `SAP HANA`.

I want to do a union of these two tables by selecting some common columns in the them.

Below are the things I want to satisfy while doing the union.

```
1) SELECT ALL product_keys from TABLE A
2) IF product_key if present in both TABLE A and TABLE B then pick product_key from only TABLE A 
3) IF product_key if not present in TABLE A then pick product_key from TABLE B
```

Comment: You tagged this question [tag:mysql]. Are you really using MySQL, or SAP HANA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the below, where the first part pulls all product keys from table_a where a match is found in table_b by using an inner join. Then the union all pulls in all keys from table_b where a match is not found from table_a by using a left join and filtering for null values from table_a.

```
select a.product_keys 
from table_a as a 
inner join table_b as b 
on a.product_keys = b.product_keys

union all

select b.product_keys 
from table_b as b 
left join table_a as a 
on b.product_keys = a.product_keys 
where a.product_keys is null
```